# when I run this code I get none, it should print the outcome of toss

Tags: python, class

When I call `get_side`, it will call toss and save the result of that in `self.side` and print it. When I call `get_side` it prints:

> This is the outcome of toss None

Why does it print `None`?

```
import random 

class Coin:

    def __init__(self):

        self.side_up='Heads'

    def toss(self):
        if(random.randint(0, 1) ==0):
            self.side_up='Heads'
        else:
            self.side_up='Tails'


    def get_side(self):
        self.side=self.toss()
        print('This is the outcome of toss', self.side)
```

Comment: Indeed, `toss` doesn't return anything, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: _Why does it print None?_ Because it sets a value, but that is not the same as **returning** a value.

Comment: Thank you that make perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

```
def toss(self):
    if(random.randint(0, 1) ==0):
         return 'Heads'
    else:
         return 'Tails'
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `None` because

```py
def toss(self):
```

... returns `None` by default and

```py
self.side=self.toss()
```

... is assigning the return of `self.toss()` to `self.side`.

The solution is to change the line above to just

```py
self.toss()
```

... since you already assign to `self.side` inside `toss`.

An alternative is to make `self.toss()` return the value as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain.